# write sms problems!

Tags: android, sms

everyone,in my app i try to write a message to sms inbox like this way `ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

             cv.put("thread_id", "111");

             cv.put("address", "100000"); 
             cv.put("protocol", "0");
             cv.put("body", serverData);
             cv.put("read", "0");
             context.getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), cv);`
but then the message inbox is empty it will no records in message inbox,if i use the other emulator send a message to this one,all the message will appear include  that i write by that code. any help? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `content://sms` content provider is not part of the Android SDK, may not work on some devices, may not work with some SMS client apps, and may not work in future versions of Android. Please do not use it.

Answer (score 0):

Look around the sms:// uri !

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html

Answer (score 0):

I know this is extremely old, but I was looking for something else when I came across this.

Try using

```
content://sms/sent
```

instead of

```
content://sms/inbox
```

That's what I use in my app, and it works fine. Also, I only use

```
cv.put("address", ...);
cv.put("body", ...);
```

But it should be more like:

```
cv.put("address", phoneNumber);
cv.put("body", smsText)
```

Where "address" is phone number of the person who sent the SMS, and "body" is the text contained within the SMS.

You might be able to use those other ones, but it's probably not necessary. Especially

```
cv.put("read", "0");
```

I assume that line sets it as unread, but it will be unread by default.

I hope this helps someone out there.